# Following a Youtube Instagram Graph API Tutorial but I can't seem to login to Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am following [Justin Slope's API Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEDKOcPuXlU&list=PL0glhsZ01I-BAFwPmQBWMNqUDnkSlOR6r&index=4) which was made in 2020.

This is the code that I pasted with some changes on the redirect URLs and using a site that is ok with the developer website.

```
    $creds = array(
    'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
    'persistent_data_handler' => 'session'
);

// create facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook( $creds );

// helper
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// oauth object
$oAuth2Client = $facebook->getOAuth2Client();

if ( isset( $_GET['code'] ) ) { // get access token
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch ( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e ) { // graph error
        echo 'Graph returned an error ' . $e->getMessage;
    } catch ( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) { // validation error
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error ' . $e->getMessage;
    }

    if ( !$accessToken->isLongLived() ) { // exchange short for long
        try {
            $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken( $accessToken );
        } catch ( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) {
            echo 'Error getting long lived access token ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $accessToken );

    $accessToken = (string) $accessToken;
    echo '<h1>Long Lived Access Token</h1>';
    print_r( $accessToken );
} else { // display login url
    $permissions = [
        'public_profile', 
        'instagram_basic', 
        'pages_show_list', 
        'instagram_manage_insights', 
        'instagram_manage_comments', 
        'manage_pages',
        'ads_management', 
        'business_management', 
        'instagram_content_publish', 
        'pages_read_engagement'
    ];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI, $permissions );

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">
        Login With Facebook
    </a>';
}
```

Whenever I try to use the code this is always the output been trying for about an hour by the time this is posted

[image]

I tried changing the graph versions and double-checking redirects and I am still stumped on this.

Comment: And the constants `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET` actually exist and contain the appropriate values? What does the actual login URL this creates look like?

Comment: @CBroe yes the client ids , state, and redirect uri were shown when I hovered on the login to facebook link and not the constants

https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=numbershere&state=numbershere&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.7.0&redirect_uri=mywebsite%2Finflu_profile%2Finflu_profile.php&scope=public_profile%2Cinstagram_basic%2Cpages_show_list%2Cinstagram_manage_insights%2Cinstagram_manage_comments%2Cmanage_pages%2Cads_management%2Cbusiness_management%2Cinstagram_content_publish%2Cpages_read_engagement

Comment: What happens when you try without asking for any specific permissions?

Comment: @CBroe, ah that helped had to clear it out for me to actually login to FB, searched a bit about this and it seems i have to have a privacy URL now to get advanced access on the developer site to get more features unlocked, odd that he didn't mention it on the tutorial or maybe this is a more recent change?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the help by the way really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove almost all of the stuff on the permissions 'pages_show_list' was the only thing left since the data isn't supported on the standard access on the Facebook developer website, have to get a privacy URL to get full access to all the other permissions.